# Can't get tiles to display

Tags: java, swing

I am following a series of tutorials for Java game development tutorials. I already have a basic knowledge of Java, from thenewboston, if that helps. Anyway, I was stuck on this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hN1v1ZhITDc&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PL54DB126285ED0420 The program I am creating for this tutorial is sort of like a 2D Minecraft, and at this point, the program should display a window with several tiles of dirt, stone, and sky in specific order. When I run it, it just displays a blank JFrame and I get these errors:

```
at mineGameMain.World.draw(World.java:80)
at mineGameMain.GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:91)
at mineGameMain.GamePanel.gameRender(GamePanel.java:85)
at mineGameMain.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:51)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have three classes, Main:

```
package mineGameMain;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    GamePanel gp;

    public Main(){

        gp = new GamePanel();
        setSize(500, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        add(gp);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main m = new Main();

    }

}
```

GamePanel:

```
    package mineGameMain;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

        //Double Buffering
        private Image dbImage;
        private Graphics dbg;
        //JPanel variables
        static final int GWIDTH = 500, GHEIGHT = 400;
        static final Dimension gameDim = new Dimension(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
        //Game Variables
        private Thread game;
        private volatile boolean running = false;

        //Game Objects
        World world;

        public GamePanel(){

            world = new World();
            setPreferredSize(gameDim);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocus();
            //Handle all key inputs
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

                }
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

                }
                public void Typed(KeyEvent e){

                }           

            });

        }


        public void run(){
            while(running){

                gameUpdate();
                gameRender();
                paintScreen();

            }

        }

        private void gameUpdate(){
            if(running && game != null){
                //Update game state


            }

        }

        private void gameRender(){
            if(dbImage == null){

                dbImage = createImage(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
                if(dbImage == null){

                    System.err.println("dbImage IS STILL NULL SO SHUTUPBEQUIET!");
                    return;
                }else{
                    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();

                }

            }
            //Clear the screen
            dbg.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            dbg.fillRect(0, 0, GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
            //draw Game Methods
            draw(dbg);
        }

        /*Draw all game content in this method*/
        private void draw(Graphics g) {

            world.draw(g);

        }

        private void paintScreen(){
            Graphics g;
            try{
                g = this.getGraphics();
                if(dbImage != null && g != null){

                    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);

                }

                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

            }catch(Exception e){

                System.err.println(e);

            }


        }


        public void addNotify(){

            super.addNotify();
            startGame();

        }

        private void startGame(){

            if(game == null || !running){
                game = new Thread(this);
                game.start();
                running = true;

            }

        }

        public void stopGame(){
            if(running){
                running = false;

            }
        }

        private void log(String s){

            System.out.println(s);

        }
    }
```

And finally, World:

```
package mineGameMain;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class World {

    private Rectangle[] blocks;
    private Image[] blockImg;
    private final int arrayNum = 500;
    //Block images
    private Image BLOCK_DIRT_TOP, BLOCK_DIRT, BLOCK_STONE, BLOCK_SKY;

    private int x, y;

    public World(){

        BLOCK_DIRT_TOP = new ImageIcon("/MineGame/src/mineGameMain/Tile_Grass.png").getImage();
        BLOCK_DIRT = new ImageIcon("/MineGame/src/mineGameMain/Tile_Dirt.png").getImage();
        BLOCK_STONE = new ImageIcon("/MineGame/src/mineGameMain/Tile_Stone.png").getImage();
        BLOCK_STONE = new ImageIcon("/MineGame/src/mineGameMain/Tile_Sky.png").getImage();
        blocks = new Rectangle[500];
        blockImg = new Image[500];

        loadArrays();

    }

    private void loadArrays(){

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNum; i++){

            if(x >= 500){

                x = 0;
                y += 20;

            }

            if( i >= 0 && i < 100){

                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_SKY;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

            }

            if( i >= 100 && i < 120){

                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_DIRT_TOP;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

            }

            if( i >= 125 && i < 220){

                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_DIRT;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

            }

            if( i >= 225 && i < 500){

                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_STONE;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

            }

            x += 20;

        }

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNum; i++){

            g.drawImage(blockImg[i], blocks[i].x, blocks[i].y, null);

        }

    }

}
```

Thank you for your time. If I did something wrong by posting this or if I left out any details please let me know.

Comment: *"I get these errors:"*  You left off the most important first line! For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (it can include 3 classes, but they all must be in the same source file).

Comment: `BLOCK_DIRT_TOP = new ImageIcon("/MineGame/src/mineGameMain/Tile_Grass.png").getImage();`  -- `NullPointerException` by any chance?

Comment: Thank you, what line are you talking about?

Comment: Okay, so I add "NullPointerException" underneath the line for grabbing the image?

Comment: *"Okay, so I add .."*  ..an SSCCE and the full stack trace from that altered source - so we can stop guessing and start helping.

Comment: Okay, I have NO idea how to turn this into an "SSCCE" I looked at the link and I'm still confused, and what is a full stack trace from my altered source?

Comment: *"I solved my problem"*  So enter the solution as an answer or delete the question.  Otherwise it is just 'noise'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson `BLOCK_DIRT_TOP = new ImageIcon("/MineGame/src/mineGameMain/Tile_Grass.png").getImage();` will never throw an NPE ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Find below a way to turn your question into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (actually it is a fixed version of one)

There are quite a few mistakes you should avoid in your code

- No need to implement double buffering yourself, Swing is double buffered by default
- All access to the UI should be made on the EDT (the Event Dispacthing Thread), not from a random Thread you created. You should also start your UI from the EDT, using `invokeLater`
- To paint a component, override `paintComponent` and invoke `repaint()` whenever you want it to be called.
- Never use `getGraphics` on `JComponent`, always `Graphics` objects provided as method-arguments (like in paintComponent).
- No need to extends `JFrame` here --> don't extend if you don't need to (you don't actually add behaviour to the `JFrame`)
- Make sure to call `setVisible(true)` as your last statement for the `JFrame`.
- You forgot to handle block 120 to 125 and block 220 to 225 (probably causing NullPointerException in your `draw` method (this is likely the root of your error).
- When you post a Java error, make sure to post the whole stacktrace and the message provided above the stacktrace (make also sur that people can identify your line numbers, by adding a comment like `// this is line 80 of the World class`)

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    GamePanel gp;

    public Main() throws MalformedURLException {

        gp = new GamePanel();
        setSize(500, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(gp);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static class World {

        private Rectangle[] blocks;
        private Image[] blockImg;
        private final int arrayNum = 500;
        // Block images
        private Image BLOCK_DIRT_TOP, BLOCK_DIRT, BLOCK_STONE, BLOCK_SKY;

        private int x, y;

        public World() throws MalformedURLException {

            BLOCK_DIRT_TOP = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i909.photobucket.com/albums/ac298/XxEnoAsaIxX/grass2test.png?t=1303852677"))
                    .getImage();
            BLOCK_DIRT = new ImageIcon(new URL(
                    "http://i909.photobucket.com/albums/ac298/XxEnoAsaIxX/sparsedirtandgrasstile.png?t=1300172998")).getImage();
            BLOCK_STONE = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.stonetilesupply.com/v/vspfiles/photos/MARBL-BTTCNCLASSICO-2S.jpg")).getImage();
            BLOCK_SKY = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://lacoste.scene7.com/is/image/lacoste/swatch_10_CH0783-00_SVH_24?$swatch$")).getImage();
            blocks = new Rectangle[500];
            blockImg = new Image[500];

            loadArrays();

        }

        private void loadArrays() {

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNum; i++) {

                if (x >= 500) {

                    x = 0;
                    y += 20;

                }

                if (i >= 0 && i < 100) {

                    blockImg[i] = BLOCK_SKY;
                    blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

                }

                if (i >= 100 && i < 120) {

                    blockImg[i] = BLOCK_DIRT_TOP;
                    blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

                }

                // Here missing block for 120 to 125
                if (i >= 120 && i < 125) {
                    blockImg[i] = BLOCK_STONE;
                    blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
                }

                if (i >= 125 && i < 220) {

                    blockImg[i] = BLOCK_DIRT;
                    blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

                }
                // Here missing block for 220 to 225
                if (i >= 220 && i < 225) {
                    blockImg[i] = BLOCK_SKY;
                    blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
                }

                if (i >= 225 && i < 500) {

                    blockImg[i] = BLOCK_STONE;
                    blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);

                }

                x += 20;

            }

        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNum; i++) {

                g.drawImage(blockImg[i], blocks[i].x, blocks[i].y, null);

            }

        }

    }

    public static class GamePanel extends JPanel {

        // JPanel variables

        // Game Objects
        World world;

        public GamePanel() throws MalformedURLException {

            world = new World();
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            world.draw(g);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Main();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```